# No intellisense on my classes

Tags: unity, unityscript

I've been using Monodevelop's current version and Unity 4. 
I don't get intellisense on the classes I've created but I do have intellisense on classes that are in Unity's framework. Bug or its just as it is?

I use UnityScript:

```
class SomeClass extends ScriptableObject{
    public function Test(){return "";}
}
```

In another class, when I use a variable typed as this class I get no intellisense.

Comment: You tried rebuilding, re-opening your project/soln right?

Comment: yes, i tried to rebuild, re-open the project, resync in unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There just isnt any intellisence on custom classes when using UnityScript unless they are in the same file. Which is very unconvinant.

I Switch to C# with Monodevelop.

Thanks anyways.